# Selenium + Phantomjs page fails to load

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am trying to capture information from the page contained in this url: http://www.oddsportal.com/darts/world/pdc-world-championship/results/. I am using selenium and phantomJS() (I have phantomJS installed using npm and this is working fine for other applications, note that you need either to download the binary or using NPM in order to replicate my code). Here is my attempt:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'http://www.oddsportal.com/darts/world/pdc-world-championship/results/'
waiting_period = 6
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(url)
sleep(waiting_period)
print driver.page_source
```

When I do this, I get entirely different html to the page I am targeting. It includes the message 'The page you requested is not available'. I am wondering if it is an issue either with a lack of settings/cookies, or execution of javascript by phantomjs?

Ulimately, I want to capture information from the div with id = 'tournamentTable' that is displayed when loading the page through a browser.